# $ker(\phi) \cong G/im(\phi)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm currently studying up on homomorphisms and I stumbled upon a problem that I've had some trouble coming up with a proof for.  In the problem we have $G$ being a finite abelian goup and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  We then define a map $\phi:G \to G$ by $\phi(g) = ng$, for all $g\in G$.  The problems asks to show that $ker(\phi) \cong G/im(\phi)$.

The case where $n$ does not divide $|G|$ is straight forward since in that case we know the only element that will map to the identity is the identity since the order of every element of $G$ must divide $|G|$.  Thus our kernel is trivial and hence the map is one-to-one which implies the map is also surjective and thus $im(\phi) = G$.  Thus in this case it is easy to see that $ker(\phi) \cong G/im(\phi)$.

I am having a problem when $n$ divides $|G|$.  The kernel should be all elements whose order is equal to $n$ and the identity but that is where I am getting stuck.  I don't know how to proceed.  I would be appreciative of any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: $n$ not dividing $|G|$ does not mean that $ord(g)$ does not divide $n$. We might still have a non-trivial kernel. For example, $G=\mathbb{Z}_6$, $n=4$. In this case $3\in \ker(\phi)$

Comment: Oh I see that now.  I should of thought about a case like that.

Comment: Is the group operation, addition?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: put $d= \frac{|G|}{\gcd (|G|, n)}$. What can you say about $x\mapsto dx$ ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  I had a couple ideas when I tried some different cases of $G = \mathbb{Z}_k$ and $n$ but when I considered $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ most of those ideas didn't work.

Comment: Do you see that it's a morphism ? Can you determine its image and its kernel ?

Comment: In my examples the kernel appears to be elements whose order divides $gcd(|G|,n)$.  The image of the map I am not as certain about.

Comment: Are you certain of that ? Imagine $n$ and $|G|$ are coprime, so that $d= |G|$ : do you think the kernel is $\{0\}$ ? In fact I'm surprised you'd even find an example where this is the case

Comment: I see what you mean.  If $d = |G|$ then our kernel would be all of $G$.

Comment: Can you try to see the general case ?